# jQuery delete everything except url in a string

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery and I want to delete everything in this string except for the url(http://momio.me/temporary//assets/cat_9_2.png&quot)

```
<div class="game1-sprite noBounceEffect trans_on" style="left: 135px; top: 202px; background-size: 86px; background-image: url(&quot;filesystem:http://momio.me/temporary//assets/cat_9_2.png&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 20% 90%;">
<div class="game1-door open"></div>
<span class="whiteText"></span>
```

Comment: Do you (want to) manipulate strings, or DOM elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first use jQuery to select the DOM element:

```
var el = jQuery('.game1-sprite');
```

Next, use the `.css()` method to obtain the content of `background-image`:

```
var bgImg = el.css('background-image');
```

Now, locate the start position of the URL:

```
var startPosition = bgImg.indexOf('http');
var url = bgImg.slice(startPosition, bgImg.length - 2);
```

Finally go ahead and set the new value:

```
el.css('background-image', url);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Pull out the URL with regex, assign it to a variable, then add with `.css()`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function findURL(input) {
        var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^ ]*)/;
        var urlFound = input.match(urlRegex)[1];
        return urlFound;
    }

    var bg = $('.game1-sprite').css('background-image');
    var url = findURL(bg);

    $('.game1-sprite').css('background-image', url);

});
```

Comment: Thanks you, do you have a sugestion of how to do it?